# Elementwise bitwise-XOR numpy matrix with numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, bitwise-operators

Suppose that we are given a two dimensional matrix `A` of `dtype=uint8` with `N` rows and `M` columns and a `uint8` vector of size `N` called `x`. We need to bit-wise XOR each row of `A`, e.g. `A[i]`, with the corresponding element in `x`, i.e. `x[i]`.

Currently, I am doing this as follows, but think that there are more efficient ways of doing that with `numpy` vectorization capabilities.

```
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    A[i,:] = np.bitwise_xor(A[i,:], x[i]
```

This is the row wised XOR. Besides this, this XOR needs to be applied column-wise, too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Row-wise : `np.bitwise_xor(A,x[:,None])`. Col-wise : `np.bitwise_xor(A,x)`.